# C# if condition for character cell value in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I'm having a coding problem in how can i check this to work with a character value instead of an integer? The code works if condition value is an integer but the cell value contains either 'I' or 'A'. I tried cellvalue.split but gives me an error.

```cs
if (int.Parse(cellvalue.Value.ToString()) == 'A')
                    statcell.Value = Properties.Resources.icons8_login_rounded_filled_100;
                else
                    statcell.Value = Properties.Resources.icons8_folder_50;
```

Here's the overall code:

```cs
        private void dg_vw_actve_doc_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && !isInit)
            {
                var valueCell = dg_vw_actve_doc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                var imgCell = dg_vw_actve_doc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 0 ]; 
                char firstCharacterInCell = valueCell.Value.ToString()[1];
                if (firstCharacterInCell == 'A')
                    imgCell.Value = Color.Green;
                else
                    imgCell.Value = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

My **imgCell** variable is a column value that was added from datagridview with a columnindex of 0, while my **valueCell** variable has a column index of 1 and is not added from datagridview in editor and only appears during runtime. It's an unbound column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your int.Parse call is returning an integer, not a character.

You can get the first element of the char array of the string. This one would be useful if you later would need to use that char:

```
// Check if there was no data
if (cellvalue.Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    char firstCharacterInCell = cellvalue.Value.ToString()[0];
    if (firstCharacterInCell == 'A' || firstCharacterInCell == 'I')
    {
        // Your condition is matched
    }
}
```

You can alternatively check if the string starts with an 'I' or an 'A'

```
string cellContent = cellvalue.Value.ToString();
if (cellContent.StartsWith("A") || cellContent.StartsWith("I"))
{
    // Your condition is matched
}
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't match the character in **cellvalue** to its corresponding image in **statcell** even if the value 'A' is correct which is an unbound column in my SQL script and not databinded unlike  my statcell.Value which is an added column in the datagridview.

Comment: I'm using the **CellValueChange event** property to run this line